# Can fastlane match command potentially revoke certificates

Tags: ios, fastlane, fastlane-match

Can `fastlane match [environment]` (not using --readonly flag) potentially revoke certificates, or are only provisioning profiles affected? I have looked at the [official docs](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/match/), but it's not really clear to me if certificates are affected by this command.

I don't want to revoke any of our existing certificates in the Apple Developer Center, since we have multiple enterprise apps using both of them.

Answer (score 2):

Running the `fastlane match [environment]` command on its own will not revoke any of your certificates.

You would have to add `nuke` to the command to revoke certificates and profiles.

The following code is [taken from here](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/blob/master/match/lib/match/commands_generator.rb):

```
 command "nuke" do |c|
    # We have this empty command here, since otherwise the normal `match` command will be executed
    c.syntax = "fastlane match nuke"
    c.description = "Delete all certificates and provisioning profiles from the Apple Dev Portal"
    c.action do |args, options|
      FastlaneCore::UI.user_error!("Please run `fastlane match nuke [type], allowed values: development, distribution and enterprise. For the 'adhoc' type, please use 'distribution' instead.")
    end
  end

  ["development", "distribution", "enterprise"].each do |type|
    command "nuke #{type}" do |c|
      c.syntax = "fastlane match nuke #{type}"
      c.description = "Delete all certificates and provisioning profiles from the Apple Dev Portal of the type #{type}"

      FastlaneCore::CommanderGenerator.new.generate(Match::Options.available_options, command: c)

      c.action do |args, options|
        params = FastlaneCore::Configuration.create(Match::Options.available_options, options.__hash__)
        params.load_configuration_file("Matchfile")
        Match::Nuke.new.run(params, type: type.to_s)
      end
    end
  end
```

The `nuke` argument is [documented here](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/match/#nuke) on the page you linked to in your answer.

You can also review what the `nuke` argument does through its source file, [found here](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/blob/master/match/lib/match/nuke.rb).

Comment: So using match without nuke will only affect provisioning profiles (generate new ones if necessary). The signing certificates will remain unaffected. It's what I expected, but just needed to make sure. Thanks!

Comment: @oyvindhauge No problem, this is the kind of thing you don't want to be wrong with.